# Can't use a Variable for both fields (Text and Selecteditem)

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted to use `Disk.Diskvolume` as a Global Variable so it contains the things from `Listbox1`. When making the same Variable as text for a label, it throws an error that says:

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
```

I made a static class called `Disk` and included `Diskvolume` as a static object. I made it so it uses an item from a `listbox1` whenever its index has changed, but it seems that it doesn't work for `Label.text`; when using a string it doesn't work with `Listbox1.selectedItem`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static class Disk
        {
         public static string Diskvolume;
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //The Labels Will Change depending on the Chosen DriveLetter
            Disk.Diskvolume = ListBox1.SelectedItem;
            Label2.Text = Disk.Diskvolume;
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

I expected `Disk.Diskvolume` to work on both `Listbox1.selecteditem` and `Label2.text`.

My problems are particularly in Line 15 and 16, and it has to do with the Public static.

Comment: "SelectedItem" is an object. I think you want to put ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.SelectedItem);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may write:

```
Disk.Diskvolume = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

It takes the selected item object of the listbox then call the standard `ToString()` method which pattern is to return a readable string representation/meaning of the object.

It is this string that is shown in the listbox to the user:

- If the items are strings, it returns the strings themselves.
- If the items are numbers, it returns the numbers converted to a string.
- If the items are other objects, same type or mixed types, it returns by default the name of the type of these objects or what has been coded in the overrided `ToString()` method of these types.